# How to configure non-admin account to install updates for Java, Adobe Acrobat Reader on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, updates, non-admin

How to configure non-admin users to allow them to install updates for Java and Adobe Acrobat Reader without needing for administrator password on Windows 7. Updates for Microsoft products install without problems.

This can be Active Directory (Windows 2003) solution, or computer based (employable through GPO or login script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than focusing on how to give user's this ability, I'd recommend focusing on leveraging software deployments via active directory.  There is the built in ability to deploy MSI installations and the ability to use scripting for EXE installers.

A good resource for MSI deployments would be [AppDeploy](http://www.appdeploy.com), and this seemed good (found via Bing search) - [Using Group Policy to Deploy Applications](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Deploy-Applications.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Updates and Adobe use BeyondTrust PowerBrower for Desktops: pm.beyondtrust.com.  I'm working through the Java Update though.

Disclaimer: I work for BeyondTrust, apologies if this reply is out of line for this forum.

Comment: It's okey as long as the answer is correct :-) This seems like a good solution however i would prefer some non-money related solution. While i wouldn't mind to pay, my company wouldn't want to invest in that.